# Wrong height value in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

These three `console.log()` from here:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class FixedTopNavigation extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.topNav = React.createRef();
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.topNav.current.offsetHeight);
        console.log(this.topNav.current.clientHeight);
        console.log(this.topNav.current.scrollHeight);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <nav ref={this.topNav} id="topNav" className="fixed-top navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
                <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#sideNav" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">Biometrics</a>
            </nav>

        )
    }
}
```

all returns **18** instead of **45.13** *(or at least one of them, and it is the rendered height of the nav bar when looked in the dev console)*

If the `componentDidMount()` does not return the right value, then what would be the way to properly get the right one?

Most answers/tutorial more or less use the same way *(except with the way the ref is created)*, tha's why I don't understand why this code does not work.

Comment: can you give `getBoundingClientRect` a try [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), also can you also share the css as without those its hard to verify

Comment: @warl0ck those classes are from Bootstrap

Comment: I tried the same code I am getting height as 56, which is the actual final height and I have used the bootstrap lib as you said fro react check this [codesandbox snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/kmnq5vrxkv?fontsize=14)

Comment: @warl0ck it seems that the **18** is the height of the `<nav>` when there is no style, I noticed this after removing the import of Bootstrap. And also copied your code, and still the same result

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can possibly achieve this.

With a setTimeout() hack

```
componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.topNav.current.clientHeight);
  }, 1);
}
```

With findDOMNode()

```
componentDidMount() {
  let compRef = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.topNav);
  console.log(this.compRef.clientHeight);
}
```

Comment: The first code returns **16**. What import should I use for the second code?

Comment: @CarlBinalla import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom';